# How can i have a pages text change based on the button clicked on the previous page in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, checkout

So i have a Pricing Table with 3 options, all on Upgrade.aspx.

1. 'Starter'
2. 'Champ'
3. 'Master'

There is a button for each option. They will all navigate to Payment.aspx, but i want some variables, such as cost, and plan name, to be different based on what button they clicked on the previous page.

So if they clicked 'Starter' button, the Payment.aspx page would say Starter. But if they clicked the 'Champ' button, the Payment.aspx page would say Champ.

Comment: You could use session variables, query string or store in database. What have you attempted so far?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: this does not seem to be that difficult.. there are many ways to skin this cat you could session variable the information you could use a masterpage and based on the value of the button that's passed along with using URI class you could determine this you could create your own method that GetsCurrentPageName based on a menu item or button that was selected..

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this. It seems a little ambiguous what would work best for your situation however.

One option is to create a singleton class with a variable which you set via button handles (IE sets the variable to "Starter" if that button was pressed).

Then the view for the Payment.aspx page could pull the information from the singleton class or consume it however you want it to.

You could also use form data, cookies, databases, and a variety of other things. It depends on where you want to store the data and how is easiest for you to store it.

There are a ton of facilities for this kind of event handling. I'd recommend looking at this article and see how it works for you [MSDN - Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.140).aspx)